# Expanding metre sticks

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion

Given the Universe is expanding. Therefore everything within the U is expanding, in all dimensions, subatomic to cosmic. Then all metre sticks are expanding. The question: How can we measure U expansion with metre sticks that are also expanding? Alice only knew she had grown ten feet tall by comparing herself to her surroundings.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5):

Space is expanding. However, nearby atoms (e.g. those in a metre stick) are not moving away from each other because the inter-atomic forces restore them to their original positions.

[image]

Similarly, as the space between the earth and the sun increases (at an insignificant rate), the gravitational force restores the earth and sun back to their equilibrium distance.

Comment: Great visual explanation for this common (and reasonable) question.

Comment: This is true, but only for a constant rate of expansion. In an increasingly accelerating universe the newly created space does have a non-trivial effect, hence the possibility for a "big rip" event.

Comment: Also we should note that the current expansion rate is about $2\times 10^{-18}/\mathrm{second}$.  This tiny expansion is completely swamped by thermal vibrations that are many orders of magnitude greater.